# Initialize byte[] in java

Tags: java, byte

I have seen the following byte initialization in a tutorial. I just want to ask whether the array includes 17 bytes after initialization and if yes why did he not use 11 hexadecimal to get a decimal value of 17?

```
byte[] decoded = new byte[0x0f + 2];
buffer.readBytes(decoded)
```

Comment: Not enough context to answer second question. Idle speculation - the author is trying to communicate that a few extra bytes are included -- e.g., for line separators , null bytes, or failsafe padding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the array will have a length of 17 bytes.

As to why the programmer did this, it's impossible to know from what you've posted. My guess is that `0x0f` has a special meaning within the application and the `+ 2` is two bytes of additional buffer space and 2 also has some special meaning.